# Why bool property with default value couldn't set with different value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have set true as default value of my boolean Active property in my csharp entity class. But I can't set it false in my method. I set it to false but after invoke Save method of the  repository pattern service instance, I see it was true again. Why could it happen?

```
   public class BaseEntity
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            private DateTime createdAt;
            public DateTime CreatedAt
            {
                get
                {
                    if (createdAt == null)
                    {
                        createdAt = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    return createdAt;
                }
                set { createdAt = value; }
            }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            [DefaultValue(false)]
            public bool Deleted { get; set; }
            public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    
            public BaseEntity()
            {
                if (createdAt == null)
                {
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }

public class OrderDetail:BaseEntity
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TokenExpire { get; set; }

}
```

DB save for set false:

```
       foreach (var cartItem in orderingItems)
        {
            var item = ItemService.GetById(cartItem.Item.Id);
            if (item != null)
            {
                var orderDetail = new OrderDetail
                {
                    CreatedAt=DateTime.Now,
                    Amount = cartItem.Count,
                    Item = item,
                    Price = item.Price.HasValue ? item.Price.Value : 0
                };
                orderDetail.Active = false;
                orderDetailList.Add(orderDetail);
            }
        }

        decimal totalOrderAmountValue = orderingItems.Sum(i => i.Item.Price);
       string totalOrderAmount = totalOrderAmountValue.ToString("F", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
        var newOrder = new Order();
        newOrder.Active = false;
        newOrder.OrderDetails = orderDetailList;

        newOrder.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        newOrder.Owner = orderUser;
        OrderService.Insert(newOrder);
        OrderService.Save();
```

Migration code to set default value in database:

```
builder.Entity<OrderDetail>().Property<bool>("Active").HasDefaultValue(true);
```

Comment: `default(bool) == false`. It's impossible to tell the difference between unmodified, and explicitly `false`. Instead you can use a `bool?` private field, with the property `get => _value ?? true;`. EF Core should load / save the field.

Comment: That's not a migration, that's the DbContext model configuration. `false` is the default for a bool. Where did you set it to `true`? You wouldn't have to do anything if you wanted to default to `false`. Your question says `I have set true as default value of my boolean Active property`

Comment: I fixed it. It must be 'true'.

Comment: The reason I asked you to post your EF code is that we still don't know what's going on. There's still no code that sets the default for `Active` to true. The model configuration method is still missing. `builder.Entity<OrderDetail>().Property<bool>("Active").HasDefaultValue(false);` is only part of it. Is there a trigger that sets the field in the database perhaps?

Comment: Let me check also that trigger stuff.

Comment: EF tracks changes to an object by comparing its original and current values. It can't detect changes made before it starts tracking an object. For new objects that happens when you call `DbContext.Attach`, `DbContext.Insert` or `DbContext.Update`. You didn't post the contents of your `Insert` method but I assume it calls one of those. Another issue is that the default value you configured is used when a property has the type's default value. For `bool`, that's false. So either you have to set `Active` to false *after* attaching, or you need to use `bool?` whose default is `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bool` can have two values, `true` or `false`. You have set the default value to `true`. This means it will be true instead of the default value of the column if you do an insert. The default value of the column is `false`. There is no way for EF to tell if `false` was set as the default value or explicitly set as the value so a value of `false` will always be overridden by the default `true`. One option would be to make the column and nullable bool (`bool?`). Then the default value would ne `null` and your explicit `false` value will be preserved and entered into the DB.